# How to read a json file in databricks from any workspace folder

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I have a simple json file(test.json) located in workspace folder(TestWS) I created as shown below:
[image]

I want to read the json file from a notebook present in Repo Workspace.

I am using simple command in python

```
import json

with open(f"/TestWS/test.json","r") as f:
    js = json.load(f)
```

but all try in vain, I read and checked in workspace only Repo folder is accessible not other, but if its true is there any other workaround we can have to read it that way.

If I am using dbutils then only notebook I can execute using (dbutils.notebook.run('location',timeout)) but I need to read json for my use case. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need to use path like `/Workspace/TestWS/test.json` or `file:/Workspace/TestWS/test.json` in spark context.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the notebook in `Repo`.

[image]

and Json file in workspace.

[image]

Code:

```
import json
with  open(f"/Workspace/TestWS/one_piece.json","r") as f:
    js = json.load(f)
display(js)
```

[image]

Or

```
spark.read.json("file:/Workspace/TestWS/one_piece.json").show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @JayashankarGS Thanks alot for your answer, I have checked your answer but I don't know why in my dbx its not working, Its still showing 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Workspace/TestWS/test.json'
But I have checked the json is present in given workspace.  I think is there any plugin or options in settings I have to enable to read it or it because of my dbx version, I am using 9.1 LTS

Comment: I think yes, I tried to spin cluster more than 9.1 LTS like 12.1 LTS and I can clearly see the folders there in workspace but in 9.1 LTS I only see Repo folder. But in my client environment the Prod cluster is 9.1 only so for now I have to see the workaround only.

Answer (score 0):

For Databricks Runtime (DBR) 9.1, the Workspace File System (WSFS) is available only for Databricks Repos and only if it's explicitly configured in the Admin settings (another option is only to start with DBR 11.x).  As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/files/workspace#--enabling-workspace-files) says:

> **Workspace files** are enabled everywhere by default for Databricks Runtime 11.2 and above.

so you need to upgrade if you want to use it outside of Repos.